# Block "business_term" not rendering

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, static-block, ce-1.9.2.4

i try to show the business terms on a simple page but my block isn't rendering.

The page which calls the block:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="business_terms"}}
```

The block itself with the settings:

> identifier: business_terms
>
> status: enabled
>
> content: test

---

Nothing special here but the output I get is the page title with empty content.

My Magento Version is 1.9.2.4

My guess: the problem belongs to the permission changes which comes up in 1.9.2.2(?). So i try to set the permission for the block in **CMS -> Permissions -> Blocks** with

> Block name: business_terms
>
> is allowed: yes

But no luck. Could you give me some advice, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block name should be `cms/block` and not your block id. Block name is actually the type of the block that must be allowed.

Comment: @jbl90 feel free to upvote and/or mark your question as answered so it'll benefit for others

Answer (score 1):

You need to white list **cms/block** instead of **business_terms**

from Admin > System > Permissions > Blocks

You can see there is block name not identifier have you added

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Raphael was a little faster so i accept his answer.